# Just need to know if my way of printing pattern in c++ is efficient , or there is an another way to do it efficiently

Tags: c++

I have posted a code to print the pattern given below . just need to know if there is another efficient way to do it .

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
        cout<< string (i+1, '*') << '\n';
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This code prints a pattern as drawn below:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: There is no need for strings in this program.

Comment: Each time around the loop your program converts an integer to a string then makes a substring of that string. That doesn't sound efficient to me, but really the only way to answer question about efficiency is to try different methods and time them. There really is no other way.

Comment: And you do have to wonder why you're concerned about the efficiency of a program that produces five lines of output in a fraction of a second. Does it really matter?

Comment: Perhaps better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Yes, you could write the same program with terrible efficiency, and you won't notice the difference.  If instead you had 10 thousand, or a million lines to generate, then you should have a concern.

Comment: Hint: `1` -> `12` is `j *= 10; j += ++i` for `i = 1` to `i == 5`

Comment: Try using ```printf()``` instead of ```std::cout```

Answer (score 5):

The most efficient way is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout <<
        "*\n"
        "**\n"
        "***\n"
        "****\n"
        "*****";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use lower-level stdio-style calls if you want to avoid the overhead of string manipulations and I/O streams:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int, char **)
{
   for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) putc('*', stdout);
      putc('\n', stdout);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

It's hard to imagine why efficiency would matter here, though.

Comment: why `putc` instead of `putchar`?

Comment: `putc` was the function that I remembered.  `putchar` would work equally well.

Answer (score 0):

The following is 4 lines.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << std::setfill('*'); // change fill
   for (int i=1; i<= 5; ++i)
      std::cout  << std::setw(i) << '*' << '\n';
   std::cout << std::setfill(' ') << endl; // restore fill
}
```

I will leave the measurement of run-time comparison to the OP.